# click image link and fade to new page based upon the url in the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have my image link inside a div with a url to my next page. And what i want to do is that; when the images are clicked, it fades to the new page specified by there link. if someone could help, that would be awesome.

`<div>
<a href="page three.htm">
<img src="images/Tbutton.gif" width="71" height="65" border="0" alt="" id="Tbutton" />
</a>
</div>`

Comment: please show us ur html

Comment: you need go with ajax based solution, but need to keep track of js , style etc..

Comment: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
//Fades body
    $("body").fadeIn("fast");
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Applies to every link
    $("a").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        linkLocation = this.href;
        $("body").fadeOut(200, redirectPage);
    });

    //Redirects page
    function redirectPage() {
        window.location = linkLocation;
    }
});
</script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think this should work:

> ```
> $(img).click(function() {
>   window.location = $(this).closest('a').attr('href');
> });
> ```